# NgRx Effects Combine action and selector with props

Tags: angular, ngrx, redux-observable, ngrx-effects

I'm dispatching an Action and I want to handle side effects.
The payload of the action is an `id`. Inside the `Effect` I want to `select` the object with the passed `id` from the store and combine with the `action`.
I'm having problems with the `Effect` logic.

`Action`

```
export class ActionX implements Action {
  readonly type = ActionTypes.ActionX;

  constructor(public payload: { id: string }) {
  }
}
```

`Selector`

```
export const selectById = createSelector(
  selectState,
  (state: XState, props) => {
    let index = state.entities.findIndex(obj => obj.id === props.id);
    if (index >= 0) {
      return state.entities[index];
    }
    return undefined;
  }
);
```

So far I have `Effect`

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
  actionX$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType<ActionX>(ActionTypes.ActionX),
      withLatestFrom((action: ActionX) => this.store.pipe(select(selectById, { id: action.payload.id }))),
      ...
    );
```

The `...` is where I don't know what to do.
Normally I'd do `mergeMap(([action, obj]) => // do something ))`, but WebStorm points that `[action, obj]` is of type `Observable<MyObj>` and not an array type.

PS: I have `dispatch: false` just so it doesn't throw error, when I figure out how to handle the operators I'll dispatch and action with some info from the previous operations.

**EDIT**
Now I know that `withLatestFrom` cannot be a arrow function with a parameter.
I was able to find this on stackoverflow:

```
map((action: LocalSubServiceTemplateActions.LoadLocalSubService) => action.payload.globalSubServiceId),
    (globalSubServiceId) => {
        return withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(fromLocalSubservices.getSearchParams(globalSubServiceId))));
    },
```

But couldn't work around so the next operator inside the pipe receives an array with `[action, obj]`.

Comment: `withLatestFrom` doesn't take a function as argument

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out a couple hours after posting the question, but this still doesn't solve my problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JoãoGhignatti - I'm trying to achieve the exact same thing. Did you figure this out?

Comment: If you need to combine somehow the values emitted by those streams you can pass a projection function as 2nd parameter of withLatestFrom

Comment: Did you guys ever figure this out? I have a similar problem.